# como pegar o valor de cada input e jogar cada um em uma variavel

Tags: php

boa tarde galera!
estou fazendo dessa forma para pegar o valor de cada input que esta dentro da variavel $html

ja tentei outros metodos para diminuir esse tanto de foreach para cada input, mais sem sucesso.

como eu faço para utilizar apenas um foreach ou algo do tipo, para busca todos os inputs, pegar os valores e colocar cada um em uma variavel .

estou fazendo assim.

```
$html = '
<html>
  <body>
<input name="nome" id="nome" value="carlos" type="hidden">
<input name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" value="silva" type="hidden">
<input name="nascimento" id="nascimento" value="1992" type="hidden">
</body>
</html>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("*/input[@name='nome']") as $p) {
  $nome = $p->getAttribute('value');
}
foreach ($xpath->query("*/input[@name='sobrenome']") as $p) {
  $sobre= $p->getAttribute('value');
}
foreach ($xpath->query("*/input[@name='nascimento']") as $p) {
  $nasc= $p->getAttribute('value');
}
## RESULTADOS
echo '<b style="color:red;">NOME:</b> <br />' . $nome;
echo '<br /><b style="color:red;">SOBRENOME:</b> <br />' . $sobre;
echo '<br /><b style="color:red;">DATA DE NASCIMENTO:</b> <br />' . $nasc;
```

Comment: Que tipo de input é esse? form?

Comment: isso mesmo e input de um formulario comun, e pq o site nao enviou codigo :/ ex: '< input name="nome" id="nome" type="text">' .. < input name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" type="text"> .. < input name="nascimento" id="nascimento" type="text">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
$variavel = '<html>
<body>
<input name="nome" id="nome" value="carlos" type="hidden">
<input name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" value="silva" type="hidden">
<input name="nascimento" id="nascimento" value="1992" type="hidden">
</body>
</html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$dom->loadHTML($variavel);

//use DomXPath para encontrar os inputs
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname='desaparecer';
$xpath_results = $xpath->query("//input");

$dados = [];

foreach( $xpath_results as $input ) {
    $dados[$input->getAttribute('name')] = $input->getAttribute('value');
}

unset($dom); //limpa a memoria

var_dump( $dados );
```

Comment: kkkkkk vlw mano, pior que eu ja tinha tentado isso..mais como sou novato nao soube fazer o codigo pra pegar kd um > $dados['nome']; .. agora funcionou rsssrrs

Comment: tranquilo....vc chegou bem perto...rs da um voto na minha resposta q todo mundo fica feliz :D

Comment: rsrs pior q cheguei perto mesmo..tmj vlw